# Calcular suma de ventas del dia de hoycon medidas en power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

Buen día estoy intentando calcular una nueva medida usando calculate para sumar el monto total de mi tabla Ventas y filtrar por las fechas de la venta del día de hoy, pero al mostar la medida en un card me arroja 0, siendo que si existen ventas realizadas el dia de hoy.

¿Cual podría ser el problema?

```
Ventas Hoy  = CALCULATE(SUM(Ventas[monto]),Ventas[Fechaventa]=TODAY())
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema, probablemente es que TODAY() devuelve fecha y hora y la columna con lo que comparas no tiene hora o bien tiene fecha y hora distintas.

Prueba comparando con

```
FORMAT(TODAY(), "DD/MM/YYYY")

Ventas Hoy = CALCULATE(SUM(Ventas[monto]),Ventas[Fechaventa] = FORMAT(TODAY(), "DD/MM/YYYY"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por sus respuestas lo que tuve que hacer fue crear una tabla calendario y con la fecha de esa tabla comparar

```
Ventas Hoy = CALCULATE([Total Ventas],Calendario[Fecha]=TODAY())
```